# print every third character of a user-inputted string in java

Tags: java, for-loop

Using For-Loop help me to write a program that print every third character of a user-inputted string. The characters not displayed are instead printed as underscores. A sample run of the program may look like this:

Enter a string: Constantinople

C _ _ s _ _ n _ _ n _ _ l _

myCode:

```
public class Ex02ForLoop {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //name of the scanner    
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    //initialize variable
    String userInput = "";

    //asking to enter a string
    System.out.print("Enter a string: ");

    //read and store user input
    userInput = scanner.next();

    //using For-Loop displaying in console every third character
    for (int i = 0; i <= userInput.length(); i+=3)
    {   
        System.out.print(userInput.charAt(i) + " _ _ ");    
    }
    scanner.close();
}}
```

But My output is:
 C _ _ s _ _ n _ _ n _ _ l _ _ 
need to do something to put the right qty of underscores
Thank you

Comment: Pedantic note: Every third character of "Constantinople" would be "\_\_n__a__i__p\_\_".  Your example prints the first character, and then every third character.

Comment: Well Yes, thats what I need

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < userInput.length(); i++)
{
    System.out.print(i % 3 == 0 ? userInput.charAt(i) : "_");
}
```

Comment: Yes, Thank you Mohammed a lot,only I made small change just to display it nicer.`code`System.out.print(i % 3 == 0 ? userInput.charAt(i) : " _" + " ");`code`

Comment: @KonstantinF you're welcome. Formatting the result is your personal choice, do as you like.

Answer (score -1):

Try to replace this:

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= userInput.length(); i+=3)
```

With:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < userInput.length(); i++)
  {
    if(i % 3 == 0)
      System.out.print(userInput.charAt(i));
    else
      System.out.print("_");
  }
```