# How to print every third character of a string? java

Tags: java

I am trying to print every 3rd character of a string so an example would be:
  `123456` returns `36`

But my code below returns `14`

```java
public String getEveryThird() {
    String newString = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {

        if (i % 3 == 0) {
            newString += (string.charAt(i));
        }
    }

    return newString;
}
```

Comment: Its a duplicate question. Please refer to this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35395271/print-every-third-character-of-a-user-inputted-string-in-java

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good try. The only problem is you choose the wrong remainder of the division since elements start from 0.

Try this condition:

```
if (i % 3 == 2)
```

Answer (score 4):

Your current approach is off in the remainder (as already mentioned), however a much faster approach is available; instead of iterating every character, start with the third character and increase your index by three on each iteration. Remember, the third character is at index two (`0`, `1`, `2`). Also, it is better to use a `StringBuilder` over `String` concatenation (as Java `String` is immutable). Like,

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 2; i < string.length(); i += 3) {
    sb.append(string.charAt(i));
}
return sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is returning `14` because your loop starts in `0` and `0 % 0` is equal to `0`.
Then, when it gets to number `4`, the index `i` is equal to `3`, and again `3 % 3 = 0`.

Try something like:

```
if((i+1) % 3 == 0){
    newString += (string.charAt(i));
}
```